# Custom dependencies under "nodejs/" directory can not be resolved from aws-lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to import custom dependencies from lambda layer but is not working.

Environment: nodejs8.10

I have a layer which consist of following directory structure:

```
mylayer.zip-
           |-nodejs-
                   |-util.js
```

Here, util.js has following code:

```
module.exports = function SomeFunction() {
  console.log('Told you This Doesn't work');
}
```

and in myLambda.js I'm trying to call `SomeFunction` with following code:

```
const someFunction = require('/opt/nodejs/util')
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    someFunction();
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/util'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:75)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " opt "is not in the directory structure you have shared. You probably need to fix the path .

Comment: @ArUn This isn't a relative path reference. It instead is a lambda layer which is supposed to extract given myLayer.zip under `/opt` during runtime

Comment: be sure that your zip command doesn't create additional directory like this mylayer.zip->mylayer->nodejs->..., it was a problem in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to put libs into a layer, and you do not want to publish your lib on nmp, you can **add a file or folder to the layers `node_modules` folder**.

### preventing naming collisions

To prevent naming clashes it is recommended that you use @scoped package names.

To create your own scope, go to https://www.npmjs.com/org/create and create an organization (f.e `myscope`). 
Now you can put whatever you like into `node_modules/@myscope` without risking a naming clash...

your layers folder structure may look like this:

```
mylayer.zip-
           |-nodejs-
                   |-node_modules-
                                 |-@myscope-
                                        |-utils-
                                             |-utils.js
                                             |-somthing.js
```

then you can require everything inside your scope folder:

```
const someFunction = require('@myscope/utils/utils.js')
const someOtherFunction = require('@myscope/utils/something.js')
```

### alternative solution

another way to achieve your goal is to change your lambdas `NODE_PATH` environment variable.

the default value (depending on your lambdas node runtime) is:

`/opt/nodejs/node12/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task`

#### staying within the folder structure recommended by aws

just add `/opt/nodejs` to that list:

`/opt/nodejs:/opt/nodejs/node12/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task`

having a layer like this:

```
mylayer.zip-
           |-nodejs-
                   |-util.js
```

now you can require your lib with `require("/opt/nodejs/utils.js")`

or just **`require("utils.js")`**

Comment: I could do that but I have created internal lib to easily interact with aws-sdk from lambda and I would like to have it deployed as layer so every other lambda can use it directly from layer. 
I certainly could have it pushed to npm and used it as deps but I want to avoid that extra step of publishing npm package everytime something has changed in myLib. 
Just was wondering if anyone has does this before and was able to achieve what I am trying.

Comment: yes, just copy your utils.js in your layers .zip file ito the folder `nodejs/node_modules/utils/utils.js` as I indicated in my answer. 
deploy that layer and use utils.js from all your functions. no need to publish on npm... thats just how require resolves pathes ;-)

Comment: I'm using the exact same approach im my project now... did you get it to work? if not, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Actually I haven’t tried it yet, Thanks for your response

Comment: @HolgerWill Your solution works; however, it's really a workaround as `require('utils/something')` suggests that "utils" is a **published** package (with its own "package.json", etc.). It would make a lot more sense if, alongside "nodejs/node_modules/*", the layer zip could have "nodejs/utils/something.js", and allows `require('./utils/something')` to import it. It gives a clear distinction between local modules and published packages. Putting inside "node_modules" also increases the chance of **naming collision** since the dependency chain could bring in dozens of packages with trivial names.

Comment: For folks reading my earlier comment, I just wanted to point out that, unfortunately, a folder structure with "nodejs/utils/something.js" and `require('./utils/something')` does not currently work. If anyone has a folder structure that allows such require pattern, please share.

Comment: you are right about the possible naming clashes. one common way to prevent that is to use scopes in the example above the folder structure would be better of looking like this: `/nodejs/node_modules/@myscope/utils/something` and `require(@myscope/utils/something)`

Comment: I found a way to achieve what you want, just add `/opt/nodejs` to your `NODE_PATH` then you can require everything in there... updated my answer again...

Comment: putting something into `node_modules` does not imply that it is published. `node_modules` is just a convention for resolving paths of dependencies... other that that it is just a folder... it just happens to be published packages that you host there most of the time ;-) ...

Comment: thanks @HolgerWill, adding `/opt/nodejs` to path works

Comment: please be aware that NODE_PATH is deprecated... it is strongly advised to not use it!

Comment: A million thanks @HolgerWill , saving all the code in `node_modules` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an "opt" in your listed directory structure; maybe you need just '/nodejs/util' as your path?

Additionally, I think you need to reference the function within your module:

```
const util = require('./nodejs/util')
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    await util.someFunction();
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: thanks, but '/nodejs/util' doesn't really live with my code and is extracted under "/opt"  directory as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).
However I will calling function from imported Module and check if that works.